# Kurento one to one video call recording Java

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

I want to recorde streaming on server for that I install Kurento Media Server as 
https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html#kurento-media-server-installation

Then follow this 
https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/tutorials/java/tutorial-5-one2one-adv.html

but with version 6.4.0, my server get started as

```
root@webrtc:~/kurento-java/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording# mvn compile exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Kurento Java Tutorial - One2One Call Advanced 6.4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create-timestamp (get-build-timestamp) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (get-scm-revision) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/root/kurento-java/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /root/kurento-java/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 343b64978ee5659dde884ffeaf3dba61d48db9ea at timestamp: 1459320863044
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: master
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 326 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ kurento-one2one-call-recording ---

   .------------------------------------.
   |                                    |
   |   | |/ /  _ _ _ ___ _ _| |_ ___    |
   |   | ' < || | '_/ -_) ' \  _/ _ \   |
   |   |_|\_\_,_|_| \___|_||_\__\___/   |
   |                                    |
   '------------------------------------'
                    version 6.4.0

11:54:29.135 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                Starting One2OneCallRecApp on webrtc with PID 2784 (/root/kurento-java/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording/target/classes started by root in /root/kurento-java/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-recording)
11:54:29.148 [OneCallRecApp.main()] DEBUG - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.3.RELEASE
11:54:29.150 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                No profiles are active
11:54:30.353 [     pool-1-thread-1] INFO  - o.h.validator.internal.util.Version      -
                HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
11:54:34.651 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - org.kurento.commons.UrlServiceLoader     -
                Config file is null (usually this means that config file doesn't exist). Using default url ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
11:54:34.653 [OneCallRecApp.main()] DEBUG - o.kurento.client.internal.KmsUrlLoader   -
                Executing getKmsUrlLoad(88bf57a7-d8f1-4154-b796-ba8b99e1d744) in KmsUrlLoader
11:54:34.655 [OneCallRecApp.main()] DEBUG - o.kurento.client.internal.KmsUrlLoader   -
                Obtaining kmsUrl=ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento from config file or system property
11:54:34.657 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - org.kurento.client.KurentoClient         -
                Connecting to kms in ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
11:54:34.717 [OneCallRecApp.main()] DEBUG - o.kurento.jsonrpc.client.JsonRpcClient   -
                 Enabling heartbeat with an interval of 240000 ms
11:54:34.728 [     pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      -
                [KurentoClient]  Connecting webSocket client to server ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
11:54:37.709 [OneCallRecApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.t.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp   -
                Started One2OneCallRecApp in 9.722 seconds (JVM running for 26.297)
```

Now, how will access it on http?
http://localhost:8080/ is not responding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it on port 8080, as all tutorials are served in `https://<ip>:8443` by default, since mid December. As of [Chrome 47](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en), `getUserMedia` requests are only supported through secured origins. Though `http://localhost:<port>` is considered secure, we decided to not serve any tutorial through an insecure protocol, just to prevent users getting errors in their consoles for this reason.